# In PHP, why does the statement if($var1 = myfunction() && $var2 = myfunction2()) fails?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

In PHP, I have seen a lot of people using the this:

```
if($var1 = myfunction()){
 //do something
}
```

That way, if true the variable already holds the value you need.

Why doesn't the same work with two variables and two functions?

```
if($var1 = myfunction() && $var2 = myfunction2()){

 // Do something
}
```

When i tried using the above, I always got a "1". Even though both functions return a value. As soon as I removed the second part ($var2 = ) - it worked.

Why do I get a 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

php interprets

```
$var1 = myfunction() && $var2 = myfunction2()
```

expression as

```
$var1 = ( myfunction() && ( $var2 = myfunction2() ) )
```

So:

- `$var2 = myfunction2()` comes first
- Then `myfunction() && $var2` is evaluated
- The result of the latter expression (which is always a boolean) is assigned to `$var1`

The solution - use parentheses

```
($var1 = myfunction()) && ($var2 = myfunction2())
```

The **better** solution: avoid such expressions

Comment: I was going to include this in my lengthier answer, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why are such expressions not good? It saves me from having to call the function again inside the if statement.

Comment: @gdaniel: don't call it again. `$var1 = f1(); $var2 = f2(); if ($var1 && $var2) {}`